# Question on Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, functions, differential, rolles-theorem

> Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, continuous on$[a, b]$ and twice differentiable on $(a, b)$. If $f(a) = f(b)$ and $f'(a) = f'(b)$. Then find the least number of roots of the equation $f''(x) - \lambda (f'(x))^2 = 0$, for any real $\lambda?$

I know that I need to imagine some function, then use Rolle's Theorem, but can't think of the function. I need some insight, how should I start?

Comment: [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|127.7620).  It address "I have no clue...." questions as well.

Comment: @amWhy thank you, for helping me. I have rephrased the question, is it all right?